# Android 9 patch images appears with padding lines

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image]

My 9-patch image is **sometimes** looks like this in the app. Not always. Most of the time image looks normal. I tried:

- Clean project
- Removed thumbs.db
- Reinstalled app on device

All above not working. Anyone know where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.
 It's my mistake I didn't deleted the thumbs.db in all drawable folders that's why the image looked with lines. Now it's fine.

[image]

Comment: Anyone know what thumbs.db did with 9 patches?